# How can I retrieve data from html using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, html

I'm new to HTML and I'm trying to learn a little about the HTML tags by trying to retrieve data from an HTML String.

```
<li> 
      <div class="item" data-youtube_code="code_for_youtuber" data-feature_code="data" data-feature_url="/movies/Truman"> 
       <div class="title"> 
        <span>the title of the video</span> 
       </div> 
       <div class="image"> 
        <img src="/media/image.png" data-src="http://url_of_image.jpg" alt=""> 
       </div> 
      </div> </li>
```

I'm using the Java Jsoup library and so far I've manage to extract the `<span>` content using:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yesplanet.co.il/movies").get();
    System.out.println(doc.html());
    Elements elem = doc.select(".item").text();
```

How can I get other things such as the `data-youtube_code` and the `img src`.

Edit: 
For example:

```
System.out.println("doc...data-youtube_code");//some code that retrieves 
//data-youtube_code. The ouptup will be "code_for_youtuber"

System.out.println("data-src")
//some code that retrieves 
//data-src. The ouptup will be "http://url_of_image.jpg"
```

Comment: Could you share what is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for letting me notice, Editted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select first div and get the value by attribute

```
    Element elements = Jsoup.parse(s).select("div").first();
    System.out.println(elements.attr("data-youtube_code"));
```

Output:

```
code_for_youtuber
```

EDIT :

```
Element elements = Jsoup.parse(s).select(".item").first();
    System.out.println(elements.attr("data-youtube_code"));
    Element element1 = elements.select(".image img").first();
    System.out.println(element1.attr("data-src"));
```

Output:

```
code_for_youtuber
http://url_of_image.jpg
```

Since you are beginner i suggest you to look for this [link](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Comment: Can you also please add a way to get "img src" content. Since it's not an attr but inner tag attr() won't work