# How to get information from HTML with Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html

I want to get information which written in the name and info classes
My code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String url = "https://www.tvyayinakisi.com/tv-kanallari/";
        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30 * 1000).get();
            Elements data = doc.select("a.item");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size ; i++) {
                String title = data.select("div.channel-details")
                        .select("name")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text();
                Log.d("Title", "Title is " + title);
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve my problem?

```
HTML Code:
```

```html
<a href="/kanal-d-tv-yayin-akisi/" class="item">
<div class="channel-logo"> <span> <img src="https://www.tvyayinakisi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/m7QHWe17F1zclFk71k4mOjt9Kjilw7qxF0bXfrnq.png" alt="Kanal D HD"> </span></div><div class="channel-details">
<div class="percentage"> <span style="width: 28%;"></span></div><div class="current"> <p class="name">Şarkılar Bizi Söyler</p> <p class="info">20:00 - 00:15, Eğlence</p></div>
<div class="next">
<div class="placeholder"> Sonraki <em class="icon-arrow-right-new"></em></div><div class="text"> <p class="name">Hürkuş: Göklerdeki Kahraman</p> <p class="info">00:15 - 02:30, Ulusal</p></div></div></div></a>
```

Comment: Can you include the html code in the post? (instead of a picture)

Comment: I added the HTML code, thanks for your response. @bsheps

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: I do not get any results from this code. I think it is about the usage of .select @takendarkk

Comment: Well, you make a variable called `title` but you don't ever actually use it anywhere. What result were you expecting and where in the code was that supposed to happen?

Comment: @takendarkk no I am using it and check it with Log but nothing is coming as a result. I forgot to add the usage part to the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I retrieve data from html using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342088/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-html-using-jsoup)

Comment: @Serhat Actually I know how to get data from HTML but I have this exact problem with just this a.item class. I don't know why the result is empty for a.item class.